# How to add a horizontal line that spans the x axis in a plotly subplot figure of indicators and scatter?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am building a dashboard application that will display live data from a web API. To make the updates as efficient as possible I am currently rewriting my code to use partial property updates when new data is available instead of building the entire figure from scratch each time (approx. every 10-15 seconds).

Some of the timeseries that gets displayed have operational limits, and I want to show these as horizontal lines that span the x axis. For a non-subplot figure (`px.line` or `go.Figure(go.Scatter())` the normal `fig.add_hline` works, but I get an error if I try to do with this the subplot shown below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/brakjen/dev/akerbp/W2W_dashboard_frontend/src/app.py", line 173, in <module>
    app = main()
  File "/home/brakjen/dev/akerbp/W2W_dashboard_frontend/src/app.py", line 168, in main
    app.layout = layout_partialupdate.make_layout(app, APP_TITLE, INTERVAL_REFRESH)
  File "/home/brakjen/dev/akerbp/W2W_dashboard_frontend/src/layout_partialupdate.py", line 53, in make_layout
    dbc.Col(utils.make_kpi_graph_card(
  File "/home/brakjen/dev/akerbp/W2W_dashboard_frontend/src/utils.py", line 84, in make_kpi_graph_card
    fig.add_hline(
  File "/home/brakjen/dev/akerbp/W2W_dashboard_frontend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/plotly/graph_objs/_figure.py", line 1084, in add_hline
    return super(Figure, self).add_hline(
  File "/home/brakjen/dev/akerbp/W2W_dashboard_frontend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py", line 4122, in add_hline
    self._process_multiple_axis_spanning_shapes(
  File "/home/brakjen/dev/akerbp/W2W_dashboard_frontend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py", line 4044, in _process_multiple_axis_spanning_shapes
    self.add_shape(
  File "/home/brakjen/dev/akerbp/W2W_dashboard_frontend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/plotly/graph_objs/_figure.py", line 24028, in add_shape
    return self._add_annotation_like(
  File "/home/brakjen/dev/akerbp/W2W_dashboard_frontend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py", line 1590, in _add_annotation_like
    not self._subplot_not_empty(
  File "/home/brakjen/dev/akerbp/W2W_dashboard_frontend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py", line 4231, in _subplot_not_empty
    for t in [
  File "/home/brakjen/dev/akerbp/W2W_dashboard_frontend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py", line 4235, in <listcomp>
    "x" if d[xaxiskw] is None else d[xaxiskw],
  File "/home/brakjen/dev/akerbp/W2W_dashboard_frontend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py", line 4718, in __getitem__
    self._raise_on_invalid_property_error(_error_to_raise=PlotlyKeyError)(
  File "/home/brakjen/dev/akerbp/W2W_dashboard_frontend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py", line 5092, in _ret
    raise _error_to_raise(
_plotly_utils.exceptions.PlotlyKeyError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Indicator: 'xaxis'
```

I have the following plotly subplots figure, here without tryint add the hlines (not a MWE, but how I create the function in my application):

```py
def make_kpi_graph_card(
    component_id: Union[str, None]=None,
    col: Union[str, None]=None,
    color: Union[str, None]=None,
    limits: Union[Tuple[float, float], Tuple[None, None]]=(None, None)
) -> dbc.Card:
    specs = [
        [{"type": "indicator"}] * 4,
        [{"type": "scatter", "colspan": 4}] + [None] * 3
    ]

    fig = ps.make_subplots(
        rows=2,
        cols=4,
        specs=specs,
        vertical_spacing=0.2,
        row_heights=(0.1, 0.9)
    )

    # Add the indicators
    for i in range(4):
        kpi_title=KPI_ORDER[i]
        fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
            value=0,
            title={"text": KPI_TITLE_MAPPER[kpi_title], "font": {"color": color, "size": 35}},
            mode="number+delta",
            number={"valueformat": ".2s", "font": {"color": color, "size": 40}},
            delta={"font": {"size": 35}, "valueformat": ".2s"}
        ),
        row=1, col=i+1)

    # Add the scatter plot
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=None,
        y=None,
        line={"width": 4, "color": color},
        showlegend=False
    ),
    row=2, col=1)

    # Define x axis properties
    xaxis_props = dict(
        xaxis_tickfont={"size": 20},
        xaxis_ticks="outside",
        xaxis_mirror=True,
        xaxis_showline=True
    )

    # Define y axis properties
    yaxis_props = dict(
        yaxis_tickfont={"size": 30},
        yaxis_ticks="outside",
        yaxis_mirror=True,
        yaxis_showline=True,
    )

    # Update layout and return the Card
    fig.update_layout(template="plotly_dark", **xaxis_props, **yaxis_props)
    
    return dbc.Card(
        dbc.CardBody([
            html.H1(col, style={"color": color, "textAlign": "center"}),
            dcc.Graph(figure=fig, id=component_id)
        ])
    )
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

**How can I add a hline to the figure without knowing the xaxis data at the point when the figure is created?** Data for the figures will come in the callbacks as `dcc.Patch` objects.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the answer is simply adding `exclude_empty_subplots=False` to `fig.add_hline`. Function where limits are shown without error:

```py
def make_kpi_graph_card(
    component_id: Union[str, None]=None,
    col: Union[str, None]=None,
    color: Union[str, None]=None,
    limits: Union[Tuple[float, float], Tuple[None, None]]=(None, None)
) -> dbc.Card:
    specs = [
        [{"type": "indicator"}] * 4,
        [{"type": "scatter", "colspan": 4}] + [None] * 3
    ]

    fig = ps.make_subplots(
        rows=2,
        cols=4,
        specs=specs,
        vertical_spacing=0.2,
        row_heights=(0.1, 0.9)
    )

    # Add the indicators
    for i in range(4):
        kpi_title=KPI_ORDER[i]
        fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
            value=0,
            title={"text": KPI_TITLE_MAPPER[kpi_title], "font": {"color": color, "size": 35}},
            mode="number+delta",
            number={"valueformat": ".2s", "font": {"color": color, "size": 40}},
            delta={"font": {"size": 35}, "valueformat": ".2s"}
        ),
        row=1, col=i+1)

    # Add the scatter plot
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=None,
        y=None,
        line={"width": 4, "color": color},
        showlegend=False
    ),
    row=2, col=1)

    for lim in limits:
        if lim is not None:
            fig.add_hline(
                y=lim,
                row=2,
                col=1,
                line_color=color,
                line_width=5,
                line_dash="dash",
                exclude_empty_subplots=False
            )

    # Define x axis properties
    xaxis_props = dict(
        xaxis_tickfont={"size": 20},
        xaxis_ticks="outside",
        xaxis_mirror=True,
        xaxis_showline=True
    )

    # Define y axis properties
    yaxis_props = dict(
        yaxis_tickfont={"size": 30},
        yaxis_ticks="outside",
        yaxis_mirror=True,
        yaxis_showline=True,
    )

    # Adjust yaxis range if limits are plotted
    lower_limit, upper_limit = limits
    adjust_yaxis_if_limits = dict(
        yaxis_range=[lower_limit*1.1, upper_limit*1.1],
    ) if not any((lower_limit is None, upper_limit is None)) else dict()

    # Update layout and return the Card
    fig.update_layout(
        template="plotly_dark", 
        **xaxis_props, 
        **yaxis_props,
        **adjust_yaxis_if_limits
    )

    return dbc.Card(
        dbc.CardBody([
            html.H1(col, style={"color": color, "textAlign": "center"}),
            dcc.Graph(figure=fig, id=component_id)
        ])
    )
```